# Non-obvious real-world datasets for observational causal inference

Tags: dataset, experiment-design, causality

I am working on a project involving inference of causal direction from purely observational data, and not time series (given several assumptions, of course). I've been using the [CauseEffectPairs](https://webdav.tuebingen.mpg.de/cause-effect/) database to validate my method, but the ground truth in these datasets is based on the obviousness of true causal direction (e.g. altitude causes air temperature, age causes income). However, causal inference would be useful in the real world if it could identify a true causal direction in cases where it is not intuitively obvious.

Let $X$ and $Y$ be collections of $L$ observations of variables with dimension $n$ and $m$, respectively. I want to evaluate my method on datasets with the following characteristics:

1. There exists a non-confounded, unidirectional causal relationship between $X$ and $Y$.
2. The causal direction is not obvious. That is, reasonable mechanisms could be proposed both for the case where $X$ causes $Y$ and for the case where $Y$ causes $X$, such that an experimental intervention would be necessary to choose between the two hypotheses.
3. There exists a simple, non-costly experimental intervention that would point to the true causal direction.

The data can be continuous, discrete, categorical, mixed, etc.

The best answers would describe a set of measurements that could be easily carried out that would produce a dataset that meets the above criteria, or list some publically available data that could be used to create such a dataset.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what types of datasets you would be looking at, but I can suggest a measure.

Somers' D is an asymmetric measure of association.  It distinguishes between it is raining, therefore, there must be clouds from there are clouds, therefore, it must be raining.  It won't always work, however.  Particularly if the set is small, it is likely there won't be enough variability to create a difference.  If the effect is not obvious and the set is small enough, the power to determine the likely direction won't be there.  This is because the measure is ordinal and so some information is stripped away by losing the magnitudes.

> Somers, R. H. (1962). "A new asymmetric measure of association for ordinal variables". American Sociological Review. 27 (6).